# XML parameters in SOAP web service

Tags: web-services, soap

I'm supposed to be using a web service function which has an XML parameter. Here is the SOAP description of those parameters:

```
<SendXML xmlns="http://www.someURL.com/someLocation/gateway/1">
  <backendUser>string</backendUser>
  <backendPwd>string</backendPwd>
  <serviceId>string</serviceId>
  <receiver>string</receiver>
  <xml>xml</xml>
  <messageId>string</messageId>
</SendXML>
```

It is a .NET service it seems (the URL of it is "service.asmx").

Anyway, note the second-last xml parameter. I'm supposed to pass an XML into there. But how can that be done? Surely, if I just copy-paste my XML message in there, it's bound to corrupt the surrounding SOAP XML itself right? What's the convention? Should I use CDATA tags? If yes, how is that done? If no, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that putting just XML code in there doesn't corrupt the surrounding XML, as long as you don't repeat the initial

```
<?xml
```

line in the xml parameter. This initial line should only appear in the outer XML. Then you should be good. And I wasn't supposed to use CDATA tags either because that parses the < and > characters into some

```
&gt; or &lt;
```

notation. So just use the XML directly as a a parameter without that initial line, and you should be good.

Comment: How were you creating the message?